# NSMutableString to NSDictionary conversion returns null [On priority]

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization, nsmutablestring

```
NSMutableString * strSocketResponse = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

 strSocketResponse = //Append socket response from server which is valid JSON string
//This response is without escaping character '\'

 NSString *jsonString = @"{\"ID\":{\"Content\":268,\"type\":\"text\"},\"ContractTemplateID\":{\"Content\":65,\"type\":\"text\"}}";

 NSDictionary *dictValues1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
 NSDictionary *dictValues2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

 NSData* data1 = [strSocketResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSData* data2 = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSError *error;

 dictValues1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

 dictValues2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

 NSLog("dictValues1 : %@", [dictValues1 description]);
 NSLog("dictValues2 : %@", [dictValues2 description]);
```

NSLog value of strSocketResponse :

```
       {
    "data": {
        "elapsed": "0.171s",
        "size": "10",               
         ...
        "items": [
            {
                "code": "29688",
                "length": "17",
                ...
             }, 
            {   ...
             }
          ]
      }
   }
```

The log for **dictValues1 is always null** where as for dictValues2 is correct. The only difference I found between two is that conversion string for **dictValues1 is NSMutableString without escaping character '\'**. It is not possible to add escape character '\' in string since it is too long.

How do I deal with this problem? Sure +1 for correct answer!!

Comment: The \ doesn't actually get stored in `jsonString`, it is just the syntax you use for a string literal to include " so the chances are that your socket response string isn't valid JSON or isn't UTF8

Comment: Log the `error` variable...

Comment: Share the response string coming from server. Log _strSocketResponse_

Comment: @Gandalf : Check strSocketResponse has been added.

Comment: Have you checked it yourself that json response is valid. If not then check it like _[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:<response>];_ Check this even before appending to string. If it is not valid check what is the class type of your string object after assignment.

Comment: @Gandalf : I have cross-checked it!!

Comment: Did you check the error before reading the same question?